# turtlebot navigation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

how can i take feedback from irobot motors to build the map by vslam?
i'm using fuerte on ubuntu 11.10

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53442/turtlebot-navigation/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-01-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-01-31**:
Can u elaborate a little..what kind of feedback u want from motors...are u looking for odometry feedback??

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-01-31**:
yes,this what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The odometry reading is published on topic "/odom".

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-01-31**:
i have only irobot create,can i make this calibration to build my map?
@shade